# Why did Microsoft change project types for asp.net between asp.net 1.1 and asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

one thing is not clear to me that in asp.net 1.1 there was asp.net project type but from 2.0 version there is no asp.net project type option rather there is option called website type project.in website type project no link is created with IIS.why Microsoft design in this way from 2.0 version. i think there must be solid reason & advantage behind it and also tell me why no dll is created in bin folder until publish the website in version 2.0.
please explain the reason,advantage and MS Thought behind it if anyone knows the reason very well.

Comment: to clarify the question is why has Microsoft changed project types for asp.net between asp.net 1.1 and asp.net 2.0?

Comment: Upgrade to Visual Studio 2005 SP1 or above.

Comment: Why do you care what the reason was?  ASP.NET is currently on version 4 and the asp.net application project type was added back in?

Comment: i don't know the reason why website type project was introduce because it was asked in interview just behind the reason and thought of Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

With ASP.NET 2.0, Microsoft split the concept into two different project types: the Website project type you're describing, and the [**Web Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) project type. The main difference is the Website project type is designed to be folder-based, lightweight, [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) - essentially low-overhead where no overhead is justified. The Web Application project is a "traditional" project type: assembly-based, with a project-schema and optimized for precompilation.

In my experience the Website project type is unpopular with developers, perhaps for no other reason than it is different from almost every other project type. The limitations should theoretically make quick-and-dirty website projects more agile, but frankly I don't find the overhead of a Web Application project a concern.

MSDN covers the differences between the two here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5

Answer (score 3):

Because they forgot to add the template. That bug was rectified in SP1.

Besides, there are now two types: website + web application. Use the latter if you can, because website projects don't offer installers.